# Is better (by a performance point of view) to stack hidden elements with z-index or to move them away 'horizontally'?

Tags: html, css

For example, I have a viewport of `100px` * `100px` and 8 `<div>`.

Each of them has style:

```
position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px;
```

the `<div>`#1, if visible, should be always under the others (z-index: 0);
the `<div>`#2, if visible, should be always over the first but under the others (z-index: 100);

and so on.

Suppose that in a given moment I have to display only the `<div>` #1, #4 and #8, so I assign `display: none;` to the others.

The question is: is better to also 'move away' the hidden elements (`left: -10000; top: -10000`) or this doesn't affect the performance of the repaint?

EDIT: the question is focused on performance. What I'm asking is: once an element is assigned `display: none`, the browser renderer (I suppose) is ignoring that element during a repaint cycle. So I think that moving away is totally useless. But I noticed in my Samsung Galaxy S2 with Android 4.0.3 that having a lot of div stacked vertically is causing a performance issue, even if only some of them (2 or 3) are visible and others are hidden. When I tried to move away them, I noticed a very very little performance upgrade, so little that maybe is not existing really. And then I posted this question :)

However, there is a better way to achieve this result?

Answer (score 0):

its better to display:none; If possible don't use position:absolute if not needed.

Comment: thx for reply! i'm already using display:none, what you mean is that moving elements away is useless, right? Ah, and why should I avoid absolute positioning? thx again :)

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use `display:none` than,negative positioning

From

http://www.marcozehe.de/2012/04/24/hiding-content-untangled-hiding-vs-moving-out-of-the-visible-viewport/

> *If an element or group of elements should only become visible after*
>   *the user performed a conscious action, use “display: none;” or*
>   *“visibility: hidden;”*, depending on your requirements.
>
> If **something should remain hidden** until the user performs a conscious
>   action, use “display: none;”. Should something, **on the other hand**,
>   become visible when navigated to via the keyboard, or be discoverable
>   by screen reader users right away, use negative positioning.

Comment: Thx for the response, but I think that this rule purpose is to provide a better user experience and maybe to provide also a valid 'html design style'... but my question was focused on the performance. I try to explain better in my own question what I mean ;) thx again

Answer (score 0):

No, moving them away will not affect performance at all, except for perhaps making it a drop *slower* due to extra calculations.

Using `display: block/none` should work well.

Comment: Thx for reply! the source is your personal experience/knowledge or other? Thx again :)

Comment: Actually, it's just a guess based on intuition. :)